Angular 19 build produces empty chunk.js files
Recently updated from v17 to v19.0.0 and now the build contains multiple empty chunk.js files.
It doesn't seem to cause any problems but I'd like to spare myself deleting the empty files over and over again.
Any ideas what causes this?

Are you able to produce a narrowed down reproduction of this issue ?

Turns out running npm update solved the issue a few days later.
